# How to differentiate the submitted source in doPost()?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two or more forms that will trigger submit events within different functions.

But I don't know how to separate the doPost() into subroutines corresponding to each source sent the event.

The following code I've tried was failed.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
function doPost(e) 
{  
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();      

  // 'mainform' is the id of one of the forms with a submit button
  if (e.parameter.source == 'mainform') {
    var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;         
    doc = DocsList.getFolder('releaseTmp').createFile(fileBlob);           
  }    
  return app;    
}
```

Comment: There can be only one doGet() - please post the doGet of your script

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation: "If you call a server function with a form element as a parameter, the form becomes a single object with field names as keys and field values as values. The values are all converted to strings, except for the contents of file-input fields, which become Blob objects." [Html Service: Communicate with Server Functions - Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-communication?hl=es%20#forms)

One option is to include a hidden field to the form with the appropriate name, then read this field in the function.

Comment: no `e.parameter.source` equivalent in HtmlService when submitting a <form> ?